# The rate of convergence of $x_n$ to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ consisting of positive numbers that satisfies the following conditions:

$(1).\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n=\infty$;
$(2).\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$.

Does there exist a $d\in(0,1)$ and two positive constants $K,L$ such that for all $n>N_0$, the inequality $0<K\leq \frac{x_n}{n^{-d}}\le L$ holds ? This outcome seems quite natural, but I am not sure if there are any counterexamples. I am attempting to rigorously prove it using a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $x_n = \log(n)/n$ satisfies the assumptions, but for any $d \in (0,1)$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n/n^{-d} = 0$, and so no such $d$ exists satisfying the required condition.

Comment: Nice, though the limit should be strictly larger than 0, as OP writes.

Comment: What about $K=0$,instead of $K>0 ?$

Comment: @Math-fun I'm not sure what you mean by this? That the limit is exactly $0$ for any value of $d$ implies that this choice of $(x_n)$ is a counterexample to the statement.

Comment: @Kevin The sequence $x_n = 1/\log(n)$ (defined for $n \geq 2$, say), also satisfies your assumptions, but this time there is no upper bound $L$ for $x_n/n^{-d}$ for any $d \in (0,1)$; this shows that the statement doesn't hold, even if we ask for $K \geq 0$ instead of $K > 0$.

Comment: you are right :-)